# Xcode 7 beta swift use of unresolved identifier

Tags: php, ios, json, xcode, swift

I am very new to swift so i am following this tut to create an app login screen and send the data to mysql. However i am keep getting the following error

> use of unresolved identifier ' request'

this happens three times in the this code when I try to use request.HHTPMethod and request.HTTPBody and also in the var json and that at the data property.

I have tried to look it up but there are so many different issue involved with this error that I am lost. What do I need to do to solve this issue and make sure I don't make the same error next time. In the tutorial the codes looks the same, however I am using Xcode 7 beta 4.

> // send data to server side
>
> ```
>     let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://xxxxxxxxx.com/bfd/user-registration/userRegister.php");
>     let reguest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
>      request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
>
>
>     let postString = "email=\(userEmail)&password=(userPassword)";
>
>     request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
>
>
>     var err: NSError?
>     var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary
>
>
>     if let parseJSON = json {
>         var resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
>         println("result: \(resultValue)")
>
>         var isUserRegistered:Bool = false;
>         if(resultValue=="Success") {isUserRegistered = true;}
>
>         var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["message"] as String;
>         if(!isUserRegistered){
>             messageToDisplay = parseJSON["message"] as String;
>
>         }
> ```

Comment: not all issues are gone yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is this line ...its a typo... you write`reguest` instead of `request`

```
      let reguest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
```

it should be...

```
      let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
```

Comment: that i missed that, i think i have been over the code so many time and didn't catch it. I do however still have that 'data' unresolved identifier issues that is not resolved yet. i am going over the code again to check if i missed something.  thanks

Comment: data undefined...same thing...if this is your code then you never defined data...you have to define it somewhere in your code

Comment: the data issue is resolved but now i am getting the error about the extra argument érror'in call. I have no idea why that is. the tut i am following is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwyhCovrScQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: i am install xcode 6 as i see xcode 7 is giving me loads of issues in the code, they have changed so much that it is not beginner friendly.